# Create or edit Views brings ajax errors

Tags: ajax, drupal

I'm getting error messages when I try to create and edit views. It brings my browser window to this `admin/structure/views/ajax/display/viewtest1/page/row_plugin`, and this shows;

> [ {"command":"settings", "settings":{"basePath":"\u002F",
>   "pathPrefix":"", "ajaxPageState":{"theme":"seven",
>   "theme_token":"GmbKm2dggZsUL97PGpcpF0LFt2GWhmM3W7zw2I7NVQo"}},
>   "merge":true}, {"command":"viewsSetForm", "output":"\u003Cdiv
>   class=\u0022views-messages\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022messages
>   error\u0022\u003E\u000A\u003Ch2
>   class=\u0022element-invisible\u0022\u003EError
>   message\u003C\u002Fh2\u003E\u000A \u003Cul\u003E\u000A  \u003Cli\u003E
>   There is a security update available for your version of Drupal.

(and this goes on for a full page).

eg I click on format, it asks 'how should each row be styled', I select content, it brings up this error.

Comment: Please proivde a link to a complete paste.

Comment: eg http://www.humanrightscloud.com/admin/structure/views/ajax/display/viewtest1/page/row_plugin  also http://www.humanrightscloud.com/admin/structure/views/ajax/display/viewtest1/page/style_options  Let me know if you'd like me to give you a log in to check it out?

Comment: I've just tried downgrading my Jquery from 1.8 to 1.7, and am testing this - so far it seems to have helped solve this.

Comment: it would be better if you would incluse that link in your post.